# Makefile with two .c files and no header

Tags: c, makefile

Trying to write a makefile with two .c files and no header. However, it seems examples online have shown the makefile with a header.

So i tried to write a header file and it would tell me a function is redefined somewhere else. my header consisted of declarations of functions in both my .c files.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H 
#define HEADER_H 

void calc(void parameters); 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]); 

struct compArray
   { 
   int start; 
   int end; 
   int thr; 
   int m; 
   int r; 
   };

#endif
```

I'm positive that's not how you write a header but ideally I'd like to have my makefile without a header. Below is my Makefile:

```
all:    thr_atomic.o thr_reduce.o
gcc -o make thr_atomic.o thr_reduce.o -lm -pthread

thr_atomic.o: thr_atomic.c
gcc -c thr_atomic.c

thr_reduce.o: thr_reduce.c
gcc -c thr_reduce.c
```

Is it possible to create a makefile without a header? My two .c files are independent of each other. If so how do I go about doing that? And if not, what would I put in my header.h to tell the computer that my variables are not being redefined and are independent from each other?

Comment: #ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
void *calc(void* parameters);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
struct compArray{
 int start;
 int end;
 int thr;
 int m;
 int r;
};
#endif

Comment: also i did not, so in my two .c files i would use extern on my functions?

Comment: `void parameters` doesn't make any sense.  Maybe you meant `void *parameters`?  In any event, there's no reason to add a header just for a makefile.  Make doesn't know anything about a C compiler works (or any other compiler) other than how to run it.  It certainly doesn't know or care whether your code uses headers or not.

Comment: In the .h file, change `void calc(...` to `extern void calc(...`, and remove the line `int main(...`.

Comment: Make doesn't care if you have header files or not, and C doesn't require them if you don't have declarations which need to be shared between source files. How are your C programs related? Which one contains a`main` function and why is the other required if the first doesn't call its functions?

Comment: Also `-o make` looks very odd indeed.

Comment: I guess is really how do you write a C program with more than one source file without a header.

Comment: so this is actually for a school project and my two .c files are two different programs that have their own main but the same function name but not the same contents within the function.  and our prof wants us to turn in a makefile with the two different programs

Comment: @JaZmYn_LoVeS, if you use a .h file that has prefixed .c functions with the 'extern' keyword, then you should not use the 'extern' keyword in your .c file(s).

Comment: my understanding of makefile was it was just instructions on compiling the program. so you can just type make and the programs will compile

Comment: @JaZmYn_LoVeS, you are correct.  That is a common use for the make utility.

Comment: @JaZmYn_LoVeS, do you understand what `gcc -o make` does?  It instructs gcc to compile an executable named `make`... not the best plan.  Perhaps  you should remove `-o make` from that line, and add `-o thr_atomic` and `-o thr_reduce` to the other `gcc...` lines.  Perhaps that will result in creating the two different programs you need.

Comment: @JaZmYn_LoVeS,   ...Likely, you will still get errors...  What is the first error now listed?

Comment: I actually dont get errors...yay! i create two .o files for the two programs which is cool. Another quick question, making the .o files is all the makefile should do right?

Comment: @JaZmYn_LoVeS, a `.o` file is not (generally) an executable file (program).  If it were an executable program, you could fire it up with a command like: `./thr_reduce`.

Comment: You may want the makefile to be able to: do something with your object file (create a lib, an exe...), have cleanup rule to remove object file, have remove rule to clean everything, have redo rule to rebuilt everything. Don't call your executable `make`, this can go wrong.

Comment: to exe the object file, would i add a -o to gcc -c -o thr_atomic.c? also i will have to add a clean up thankyou for reminding me

Comment: Why not simply : `all:    thr_atomic thr_reduce <newline>

thr_atomic: thr_atomic.c <newline>
gcc thr_atomic.c -lm -pthread <newline>

thr_reduce: thr_reduce.c <newline>
gcc  thr_reduce.c -lm -pthread <newline>`

Comment: this does make a a.out so cool! if id like to rename each each file a different .out filename, would i use -o [newfilename] EDIT: nvm I figured it out hah. Thankyou everyone for the advice and feedback, you have no idea how helpful this was

Comment: @Chelmy88 Please make an answer from your comment, and, JaZmYn_LoVeS, please mark it as such. This will help us save time by not reading this answered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Makefile:

```
all: thr_atomic thr_reduce

thr_atomic: thr_atomic.c 
gcc thr_atomic.c -lm -pthread 

thr_reduce: thr_reduce.c 
gcc thr_reduce.c -lm -pthread <newline>
```

However, since it seems the two programs are totally independent, I would rather make two separate makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, you don't *need* a header file in order to compile C code using a Makefile. Makefiles don't have anything to do with source code. All a Makefile does is run a command(s) if the file(s) you've specified have been updated.

```
# Makefile
outfile: infile1 infile2
    command1
    command2
    # ^ commands MUST begin with a tab
```

If you run `make outfile`, this is what happens:

1. If `outfile` does not exist, then `make` runs `command1`, and then runs `command2`.
2. If `outfile` exists, but `infile1` *and* `infile2` have not been updated since then, `make` will do nothing.
3. If `outfile` exists and `infile1` or `infile2` *have* been updated since `outfile` was last modified, then `make` will run `command1` and then run `command2`.

That's the basics of `make` and Makefiles. The files (`outfile`, `infile1`, `infile2` etc.) and the commands (`command1`, `command2`) can be *anything* you like. There can also be any number of them present.

When it comes to compiling code, `make` is pretty useful because you can use it to recompile a binary file (also called an executable file) if the source files are changed, which is exactly what you want.

For example, this makefile creates a binary file (executable file) from two source files (and no header files):

```
# Makefile

# executable file is called "prog"
prog: a.o b.o
    gcc -o prog a.o b.o
    #   ^^^^^^^
    #    tell gcc to name the output file "prog"

# compile the first source file "a.c" to produce the object file "a.o"
a.o: a.c
    gcc -c a.c

# compile the second source file "b.c" to produce the object file "b.o"
b.o: b.c
    gcc -c b.c
```

If you do have header files, then you would need to change the compilation lines to this:

```
# Makefile

# ...

# compile a.c, which has an associated header file a.h 
a.o: a.c a.h
#        ^^^ add the header file here
    gcc -c a.c
```

If you are not clear about what header files are, then look them up somewhere or ask another question about them.